# Peolple API - Erro 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED

Tags: php, api, packages

Estou a usar o seguinte [package](https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api) para guardar contactos no serviço disponibilizado pela `Google`, ou seja, `Google Contacts`.

Pedidos do tipo `GET` funcionam na perfeição e consigo extrair os contactos corretamente. 
No entanto, quando faço um pedido `POST`, é retornado o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught Exception: { "error": { "code": 429, "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).", "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure", "violations": [ { "subject": "QUOTA_EXCEEDED", "description": "FBS quota limit exceeded." } ] } ] } } in C:\xampp\htdocs\GoogleContactsAPI\vendor\rapidwebltd\php-google-people-api\src\GooglePeople.php:132
```

Eu sei que o erro é claro, contudo, o retorno não está correto porque eu não excedi a `Cota`, somente tenho **6 pedidos efetuados**

Deixo aqui o código utilizado (as variávies iniciais não estão preenchidas porque são secretas):

```php
<?php

$clientId     = '';
$clientSecret = '';
$refreshToken = '';
$scopes       = '';

$googleOAuth2Handler = new GoogleOAuth2Handler($clientId, $clientSecret, $scopes, $refreshToken);
$people = new GooglePeople($googleOAuth2Handler);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nome = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputName"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputEmail"]);
    $number1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputNumber1"]);
    $number2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputNumber2"]);
    $city = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputCity"]);
    $state = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputState"]);


    $contact = new Contact($people);
    $contact->names[0] = new stdClass;
    $contact->names[0]->givenName = $nome;
    $contact->emailAddresses[0] = new stdClass;
    $contact->emailAddresses[0]->value = $email;
    $contact->phoneNumbers[0] = new stdClass;
    $contact->phoneNumbers[0]->value = $number1;
    $contact->phoneNumbers[1] = new stdClass;
    $contact->phoneNumbers[1]->value = $number2;
    $contact->addresses[0] = new stdClass;
    $contact->addresses[0]->city = $city;
    $contact->addresses[0]->region = $state;*/
    $contact->save();

    if ($contact->save()) {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#modalResponseSuccess').modal('show');
        });
        </script>";

    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#modalResponseError').modal('show');
        });
        </script>";
    }

}


?>
```

Alguém já passou por alguma situação semelhante ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Tens a mensagem "QUOTA_EXCEEDED"    e status 429 (Too many requests), isso é o chamado Traffic Management ou Throtting, o que permite para determinados utilizadores ou grupos limitar o numero de requests, na diagonal entre outras, protegendo de ataques DDOS e garantindo o serviço para quem efetivamente paga o seviço e não tem limites por exemplo, não conheço essa api, mas o motivo é esse, excedeste o número total de pedidos que podes fazer, ou o limite temporal (diário/hora/minuto).

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova  ola, obrigado pela resposta.
Estou com a experiência gratuita anual que a google oferece (300$ de crédito). 
A minha questão (e analisando a informação por eles fornecida) é que só fiz 6 pedidos e deu este erro. 
Pedidos `GET` funcionam na mesma.